java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The plugin specification 'io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm' has a problem:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The plugin specification 'io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm' has a problem:
This plugin is not compatible with this version of Cucumber.
Plugin specifications should have the format of PLUGIN[:[PATH|[URI [OPTIONS]]]
Valid values for PLUGIN are: html, json, junit, message, pretty, progress, rerun, summary, teamcity, testng, timeline, unused, usage
PLUGIN can also be a fully qualified class name, allowing registration of 3rd party plugins. The 3rd party plugin must implement io.cucumber.plugin.Plugin
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.createPluginIsNotCompatible(PluginOption.java:150)
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parsePluginName(PluginOption.java:125)
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parse(PluginOption.java:100)
at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:68)
at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.addPlugins(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:85)
at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.parse(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:39)
at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:120)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

Process finished with exit code 255
Tried with JDk version 17.0.10, 17.0.11, 17.0.12 all of them are giving same error. Below are my cucumber dependencies
io.qameta.allure
allure-cucumber6-jvm
2.29.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-core
7.20.1
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.20.1
test
io.cucumber
cucumber-java
7.20.1

You are using cucumber 7, with allure cucumber 6 and the error complains about allure cucumber 4.
